# Meteor JS: How do I preserve cursor position on contenteditable field between renders?

Tags: javascript, meteor

**Problem:**

I have several contenteditable elements. When a user focuses on an element, an `editing` class name is added to the element.  I am using Session object to do this, instead of jQuery. The problem is that everytime I focus on the element, it rerenders, and both the cursor position and focus is lost.

I am trying to use the preserve `method` on the element to prevent it from getting updated when the element is being edited, but cannot get this to work. Any suggestions?

**Here's my code:**

```
// Collection
Forms = new Meteor.Collection('forms');

// Fixtures
if (Forms.find().count() === 0) {
  Forms.insert({
    description: "form 1"
  });

  Forms.insert({
    description: "form 2"
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  // Helpers
  Template.forms.helpers({
    editState: function() {
      return Session.equals("fieldEditing", this._id) ? "editing" : "";
    },

    forms: function() {
      return Forms.find();
    }
  });

  // Preserve
  Template.forms.preserve(['.editing']);

  // Event handler
  Template.forms.events({
    'focus .form-field' : function (e, template) {
      e.preventDefault();
      Session.set("fieldEditing", this._id);
    }
  });
}

// Template

<head>
  <title>testproject</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> forms}}
</body>

<template name="forms">
  {{#each forms}}
    <p class="{{editState}} form-field" contenteditable>
      {{description}}
    </p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by `Spark` not considering the content of the `contenteditable` node a `value` that should be kept. Hence each render resets the content of the div, moving the cursor to the beginning.

I found closed issue that is similar https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/171 , but I don't think using `{{#constant}}` regions is a great solution in your case.

I would suggest:

- Trying one of the new preview-rendering engines.
- Creating an issue at https://github.com/meteor/meteor with your specific example.

Note, I changed your code to the following to test easier:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {    
  // Collection
  Forms = new Meteor.Collection(null);

  // Fixtures
  if (Forms.find().count() === 0) {
    Forms.insert({
      description: "form 1"
    });

    Forms.insert({
      description: "form 2"
    });
  }

  // Helpers
  Template.forms.helpers({
    timer: function(){
      return Session.get("timer");
    },
    forms: function() {
      return Forms.find();
    }
  });

  // Preserve
  Template.forms.preserve({
    ".form-field":function(n){return n.id}
  });

  Session.set("timer",+new Date())
  Meteor.setInterval(function(){
          Session.set("timer",+new Date())
  },2000);

}

// Template

<head>
  <title>testproject</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> forms}}
</body>

<template name="forms">
  {{timer}}
  {{#each forms}}
    <p class="form-field" contenteditable id="form-{{_id}}">
      {{description}}
    </p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: I am using 0.8.12 with jade and am having this issue. Any update?

Comment: @nearpoint I'd create an issue at https://github.com/meteor/meteor with your example. I don't think spacebars/blaze takes contentedible into account when re-rendering elements.

Comment: awe thats to bad, I have an autosave function to save the users data when they take a break form typing and because of the re-rendering the caret just goes to the top! Not good UX. I wish they would fix this soon.

Comment: Do you have a direct link to the issue you submitted?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't quite clear - you should create the issue, and reference #171 as it's a regression/ similar